# How to download zip files from webdav server using sardine?

Tags: java, download, mule, webdav, sardine

I am using below java class which uses sardine , i am getting only resources or zip files list in the directory, what should i use to download zip files?

```
package com.download;
import java.util.List;

import org.mule.api.MuleEventContext;
import org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable;
import com.github.sardine.DavResource;
import com.github.sardine.Sardine;
import com.github.sardine.SardineFactory;

public class filesdownload implements Callable{

@Override
public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
    Sardine sardine = SardineFactory.begin("***","***");

    List<DavResource> resources = sardine.list("http://hfus.com/vsd");
    for (DavResource res : resources)
    {
        System.out.println(res);
    }

    return sardine;
}
```

Comment: Did you find something already? I found out commons vfs allows zip AND webdav

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `sardine.get()` method. [Method documentation](https://github.com/lookfirst/sardine/wiki/UsageGuide#inputstream-getstring-url)
Don't forget to use absolute path to your file. For example: `http://hfus.com/vsd/file.zip`.

Code sample:

```
package com.download;
import java.util.List;

import org.mule.api.MuleEventContext;
import org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable;
import com.github.sardine.DavResource;
import com.github.sardine.Sardine;
import com.github.sardine.SardineFactory;
//TODO: add missing imports

public class filesdownload implements Callable{

    @Override
    public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
        Sardine sardine = SardineFactory.begin("***","***");

        List<DavResource> resources = sardine.list(serverUrl()+"/vsd");
        for (DavResource res : resources) {
            if(res.getName().endsWith(".zip")) {
                downloadFile(res);
            }
        }

        return sardine;
    }

    private void downloadFile(DavResource resource) {
        try {
            InputStream in = sardine.get(serverUrl()+resource.getPath());
            // TODO: handle same file name in subdirectories
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(resource.getName());
            IOUtils.copy(in, out);
            in.close();
            out.close();
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }

    private String serverUrl() {
        return "http://hfus.com";
    }
}
```